# Bibliography style with only the initials of the first names

Tags: bibliographies, bibdesk

I created a .bib file using BibDesk, which contains the following reference:

```
@article{Farrell:2005aa,
    Author = {Farrell, Jay and Sharma, Manu and Polycarpou, Marios},
    Cited-By = {113},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-11 16:36:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-11 16:38:05 +0000},
    Journal = {Journal of Guidance, Control, and Dynamics},
    Number = {6},
    Pages = {1089-1102},
    Title = {Backstepping-based flight control with adaptive function approximation},
    Volume = {28},
    Year = {2005},
}
```

When I generate a TeX Preview in BibDesk this entry looks as follows:

[image: ex]

In my LaTeX document I use the following code to insert the references:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{MyBibFile}
```

With the following result:

[image: ex2]

Now I would like the reference in my report to look like as in the first example, that is with only the initials of the first names.

Comment: Usually this is a bad idea, because every author has a unique way of writing their initials in papers, and this is the way they need to be cited (so that they are easily identifiable in searches etc.). Of course use of initials instead of first and middle names etc is ok, but if the author uses their middle initial, it should be preserved in the reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could proceed as follows to direct BibTeX to abbreviate first (and middle) names down to the initials, while using a suitably modified version of the `plain` bibliography style:

- Find the file `plain.bst` in your TeX distribution. (One way to find this file is to issue the command `kpsewhich plain.bst` at a command prompt.) Copy this file to, say `myplain.bst`. (Don't edit directly a file provided as part of your TeX distribution.)
- Open the file `myplain.bst` in your favorite text editor -- the one you use to edit your `.tex` files will do -- and search for the function named `format.names`. (In the version of this file that's in my TeX distribution, the function `format.names` starts on line 185.)
- In this function, look for the line

  ```
  { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Change this line to

  ```
  { s nameptr "{f. }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```
- Save the file `myplain.bst` either to the directory that contains your main `.tex` file or to a directory that's searched by your BibTeX distribution. (If you choose the second option, depending on your TeX distribution, you may also have to refresh the filename database of the TeX distribution.)
- Start using the modified bibliography style file by issuing the command `\bibliographystyle{myplain}`, and be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on the main `.tex` file to propagate all changes.

Here's how the entry in question will be typeset with `myplain` as the bibliography style:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Farrell:2005aa,
    Author = {Farrell, Jay and Sharma, Manu and Polycarpou, Marios},
    Cited-By = {113},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-11 16:36:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-11 16:38:05 +0000},
    Journal = {Journal of Guidance, Control, and Dynamics},
    Number = {6},
    Pages = {1089-1102},
    Title = {Backstepping-based flight control with adaptive 
            function approximation},
    Volume = {28},
    Year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{myplain} % note: 'myplain' rather than 'plain'
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `biblatex` with convenient options. Write:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, giveinits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MyBibfile.bib}

\begin{document}
% text + references
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This makes both citation and bibliography styles numeric. But you can choose citation style and bibliography style independently. Take a look at §3.3  of the biblatex documentation for a description of the standard syles available. Moreover, in case you use  `natbib`, you can load biblatex with the `natbib` option, that emulates natbib functionalities.

*Updated (3/9/2017)*

The old syntax for first names initials was `[firstinits]`, now it is `[giveinits]`, though.

Comment: Not explicitly, but the example shows numeric labels, and he/she says he/she uses the `plain` style. Doesn't the plain style produce numeric labels?

Comment: You're right. I'll mention that citation and bibliography styles can be chosen independently, and there exists a compatibility module for `natbib`.