# Inline citation with author year style in self defined bibliographystyle{myplain}

Tags: bibtex, citing, inline

I need the abbreviation for the first name of authors in reference, so I did what people suggested here [Bibliography style with only the initials of the first names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168749/bibliography-style-with-only-the-initials-of-the-first-names/168758#168758?newreg=7d28e299be8348368c7c6016a3e09324). But I also want to keep the author year inline citation style rather than the number inline citation. I use BibTeX. So how can I set the incline citation into autheryear style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you use a citation management package, say `cite` or `natbib`?

Comment: Thanks! I use natbib.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you (a) load `natbib` with the options `authoryear` and `round` and (b) employ the `abbrvnat` bibliography style.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Could you help me more with the reference format? I also want to add a linebreak after the authors of a reference to separate authors and title. How can I do that?

Comment: To induce a line break after the `author` block, it suffices to specify `openbib` as one of the document class options (followed by a recompilation run, of course).

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! I will make a clear statement for the problem and hope it can help more people. First I used the `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` to show the initials of the authors' first name in the reference section. And then I use the `\documentclass[titlepage,openany,openbib]{scrbook}` to let references display authors and title and journal in different lines.

Answer (score 0):

(just summarizing earlier comments in order to be able to "check off" this posting as having received a "full" answer)

- Since you use the `natbib` citation management package, use the `abbrvnat` bibliography style to generate formatted bibliographic entries with abbreviated given names placed *before* the surnames.
- To generate authoryear-style citation call-outs in the body of the document, load the `natbib` package with the options `authoryear` and `round`. Use `\citet` and `\citep` to generate "textual" and "parenthetic" citation call-outs.
- To induce a line break after the `author` block in the formatted bibliographic entries, specify `openbib` as one of the document class options. E.g.,

  ```
  \documentclass[titlepage,openany,openbib]{scrbook}
  ```

Happy BibTeXing!